# PHP and webpack-dev-server

Tags: php, html, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I use Webpack to bundle my HTML, SASS, JS, images and ...
Now I want to use PHP for my server-side programming. My problem is that I don't know how to use PHP on HTML or use them separately to forward my project. Webpack give me HTML, CSS and JS files. Now, how can I use PHP on them? Webpack, in developer mode, injects things on HTML in memory and I cannot use PHP on them. So, I cannot use reload ability of webpack-dev-server! If I use production mode, then it takes a lot of time to save codes on disk! Is there anyway to implement php in ".src" folder or inside html, and take the result on ".dist" folder? If anyone have better idea or solution, I will bethankful...

If I try to use PHP on .dist folder files, it has a lot of problems such as you cannot use contentHash on my output files to force browser hard reload and can't use web-dev-server either...

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert and neither a PHP programmer, but from what you are saying, I think you should keep your projects separated from each other, so that you only use PHP for generating your assets (html, sass, js, images, etc) in your *development environment*, while in production you won't have this PHP code running. The only thing running in your production environment would be another PHP server which serves your assets after they have been alread generated by your webpack service. Does it make sense?

Comment: Well not really, It's not important for me that codes be separated! If it is possible I would like to use PHP on the ".src" webpack folder and then, webpack-dev-server show my code results on screen. But I read somewhere that it's not possible to use PHP on webpack-dev-server! So I want a method that after dev-server product codes, then I can use PHP on them and see the result like what dev-server do with html file ... Don't know if it is possible or not.

Comment: I want to try this method. hope work!                                    
https://m.dotdev.co/using-webpack-2-hmr-in-laravel-development-2f632d6d06c6

Comment: Good luck, bro.